# Append formatted text to a EditText View

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an EditText view which I am using to display information to the user. I am able to append a String and it works correctly with the following method:

```
      public void PrintToUser(String text){
         MAIN_DISPLAY.append("\n"+text);
      }
```

The application is an RPG game which has battles, when the user is fighting I would like to display the String in RED. So I have attempted to use a SpannableString. (changed the method)

```
       public void PrintToUser(String text, int Colour){
    
       if(Colour == 0){
       //Normal(Black) Text is appended
       MAIN_DISPLAY.append("\n"+text);
        
        
       }else{
       //Colour text needs to be set.
    

       //Take the CurrentText
       String CurrentText = MAIN_DISPLAY.getText().toString();
       CurrentText = CurrentText+"\n";
        
       SpannableString SpannableText = new SpannableString(CurrentText + text);  
    
       switch(Colour){
       case 1:
              SpannableText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), CurrentText.length(), SpannableText.length(), 0); 
       break;
       }
    

     //You cannot append the Spannable text (if you do you lose the colour)
    MAIN_DISPLAY.setText(SpannableText, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }
```

This new method works and the new line is displayed is red.

**Problems**

1. Only the last line formatted is red. If a new line is set to be red the previous formatting is lost due to the way I retrieve the text

   > String CurrentText = MAIN_DISPLAY.getText().toString();
2. When I was ONLY appending Strings to the EditText it was displaying the bottom of the EditText box (the last input) now when using SetText the users see's the Top.

**Finally My Question:**

Is there a way to Append the formatted text?

*OR...* Can I retrieve the formatted text from the EditText and then when I use .setText I can keep the current format?

*AND if so...* Is there a way to focus the Display at the Bottom opposed to the Top?

*Thank you! Please comment if additional information is needed I've been stuck on this for a while now.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following modifications to `PrintToUser()` should work..

```
public void PrintToUser(String text, int Colour){
    ...
    ...
    Editable CurrentText = MAIN_DISPLAY.getText();
    int oldLength = CurrentText.length();
    CurrentText.append("\n" + text); 

    switch(Colour){
       case 1:
         CurrentText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 
                             oldLength, CurrentText.length(), 0); 
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks just what I was looking for works perfectly, Always seems so simple once you know the answer! - thanks again

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use the method:

```
myTextView.setText(Hmtl.fromHtml(myString));
```

Where the myString could be of the format:

```
String myString = "Hello <font color=\'#ff0000\'>World</font>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
SpannableText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), CurrentText.length(), SpannableText.length(), 0);
```

on

```
SpannableText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, SpannableText.length(), 0);
```

Comment: This would change all of the text to red, some i would like to have some text black.. then some red, green, blue etc..(depending on output) But thanks for your answer